# Why won't this enter the while loop?

Tags: c, while-loop

I've been tearing my hair out trying to figure out why it won't print out the test message and enter the `while` loop. Any ideas?

```
void getInput(char * string)
{
  char * tempString;
  int maxLength = 1026; // Accounts for NULL and \n.
  tempString = malloc(maxLength * sizeof(char));  

  fgets(tempString, maxLength, stdin);
  size_t len = strlen(tempString);


  while ((int)len > maxLength)
  {  
    printf("Test");
    if (tempString[len-1] == '\n')
    {
      tempString[len-1] = '\0';
      len = strlen(tempString); 
    } // if
  } // while
```

Comment: Because len is not greater than maxLength.

Answer (score 6):

`fgets(tempString, maxLength, stdin);` reads at most `maxLength-1` bytes.  See the fgets [man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) for details.

This means that `strlen(tempString)` must always be less that `maxLength`.

Did you mean to use `<` as your loop test instead?

```
 while ((int)len < maxLength)
```

Comment: or maybe `while((int) len > 0)`. note `len` never grows within the loop.

Comment: I want to compare len to the MaxLength, and if it is greater than maxLength, remove excess characters, which is what the while loop does.

Comment: @AkshaiShah the point is, there _can not_ be any excess characters. If there were - bam! buffer overrun.

Comment: @AkshaiShah `len` can never be greater than `maxLength`.  I've updated my answer to try to better explain why

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else did, let me introduct you to man pages. Just type man and the function name into Google if you don't have a Linux based OS and you'll get a description of how the function work.

[Here's a man page for fgets()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets):

> char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
>   fgets() reads in **at most one less than size** characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.

So in your code:

```
fgets(tempString, maxLength, stdin); // size is maxLength
```

You'll never read more then `maxLength-1`, this is just how the function works.